# Regular Expression to find Images links in string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this `https://images.pexels.com/photos/459225/pexels-photo-459225.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500` and I need to define if this image-link or not.

I found regular expression `/(http(s?):)([/|.|\w|\s|-])*\.(?:jpg|gif|png)/g` which define image if link has appropriate format in the end, but this regular expression doesn't work with such link `https://images.pexels.com/photos/459225/pexels-photo-459225.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500`

I am not familiar with regular expressions, so can you help me to improve this regular expression and define such link. Thanks

Comment: You have unescaped `/` character in regex

Comment: @DominikMatis `[/]` is [valid](https://regex101.com/r/RRdkwp/1) in regex literals in most JS regex implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Just modify the regular expression like that:

```
 /(http(s?):)([\/|.|\w|\s|-])*\.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png)/g
```

Comment: I downvoted because the pattern is invalid, try it on `regex101.com`

Comment: Well ok but the original expression is invalid as well

Comment: @DominikMatis `[/]` is [valid](https://regex101.com/r/RRdkwp/1) once you select the right engine. No need to rush with downvoting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape that `/` in regex, so this is correct

```
/(http(s?):)([\/|.|\w|\s|-])*\.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png)/g
```

Comment: In most JS regex implementations, in a character class inside a regex literal, unescaped `/` is valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten your existing expression significantly by collapsing some of your capture groups, as well as removing the pipe characters from your `[]` character set. Characters sets automatically behave like "OR" statements without the use of pipes.

```
/(https?:)([\/.\w\s-])*\.(?:(jpe?|pn)g|gif)/gi
```

To dissect this expression and see why it works, take a look at it on [RegExr](https://regexr.com/4jm5v).

Answer (score 0):

That regex is too restrictive because it is poorly performing domain validation so you can loosen it up like this:

```
https?:\/\/[^.]*?(\.[^.]+?)*\/.*?\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)
```

https://regex101.com/r/ZXyOkQ/2

Answer (score 0):

You can use `URL` api and `test`

```js
let str = `https://images.pexels.com/photos/459225/pexels-photo-459225.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500`
let str2 = `https://images.pexels.com/photos/459225/pexels-photo-459225.exe?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500`

let isImage = (str) =>{
  let parsed = new URL(str)
  return /(?:jpe?g|gif|png)$/i.test(parsed.pathname)
} 

console.log(isImage(str))
console.log(isImage(str2))
```